# Trouble handling TypeError when comparing two variables that are NoneType - Python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, nonetype

I'm trying to handle a `TypeError` exception where both variables are equal to `None`.

I'd like to make each of them equal to a float `0`. If one of the variable is `float`, and one is `NoneType`, it seems to correctly convert the `NoneType` var to `0`  and returns a `float` as I would expect, but I still get a type error when both are `NoneType`:

```
'<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'NoneType'
```

Why is this happening? I would expect the following function to return 0. Here is my code:

```
def test():
    market_price = None
    low_price = None
    try:
        if market_price < low_price:
            market_price = low_price
    except TypeError:
        if market_price is None:
            market_price = 0.
        elif low_price is None:
            low_price = 0.
        if market_price < low_price:
            market_price = low_price

    return market_price

print(test())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code block you set `market_price` to 0 **OR** `low_price` to 0. Both are None so only `market_price` is set to 0, `low_price` stays None and comparing fails.

```
if market_price is None:
    market_price = 0.
elif low_price is None:
    low_price = 0.
```

Split the following statement to:

```
if market_price is None:
    market_price = 0

if low_price is None:
    low_price = 0
```

That way the program will set up both variables to 0 correctly.

Answer (score 1):

So,  Let's go over your code... (comments inline with a #)

```
def test():
    market_price = None  #  Sets variables to None
    low_price = None
    try:
        if market_price < low_price:  # This will ALWAYS throw error because < isn't a good operator for comparing None
            market_price = low_price  # Never gets here
    except TypeError:                 # This function will Always hit exception (which is probably already wrong)
        if market_price is None:  # This is true
            market_price = 0.     # so this gets set to a float
        elif low_price is None:   # Since above is true this doesn't get checked (ie elif rather than a regular if)
            low_price = 0.        # This never gets set
        if market_price < low_price:  # You are comparing None with less than operators again (which would fail)
            market_price = low_price

    return market_price

print(test())
```